# Clarification for binomial distribution problem

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I am not quite understanding the solution to this problem.

You are working on a difficult passage from a new piece you are learning on the piano.
You wish to play it correctly 4 times before calling it a day. If you have a probability
of 2/3
of playing it correctly on every attempt, and the attempts are independent, what is the probability that you attempt to play it at least 8 times?

Solution:

[image]

Why it `(n-1) nCr 3` and not `n nCr 4` ? From my understanding there are 4 'successes' for each n practice sessions.

Comment: PS: You are actually dealing with a "[negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution)", which is rather different from a Binomial distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to find the probability of playing correctly $3$ times among the first $n-1$ tries, then correctly on try $n$ (and you don't care what happens after that), for some $n$ between $4$ and $7$

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X<8)~=~& \sum_{n=4}^7\mathsf P(X=n)
\\~=~&\sum_{n=4}^7\binom {n-1}3(\tfrac 23)^{3+1}(\tfrac 13)^{n-4}\end{align}$$

---

PS: You are actually dealing with a "[Negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution)", which is rather different from a Binomial distribution.